# find path between root and multiple of 5

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

I am facing hard time to implement a program for finding the path to a node from b-tree root which is a multiple of 5.

Example:

```
     12
    /  \
   4    7
  /\    /\
 5  3  4 10
```

Consider this as the tree.
 Program should print

```
12 -> 4 -> 5

12 -> 7 -> 10
```

Edit:

Yes I have tried and following is the algo I am following: I traverse in-order and compare the values for multiple of 5. If it is, I start adding the nodes in a LinkedList and return that list back. But this approach works only if I have one multiple of 5. If there are more multiples, it fails.

Following is what I have tried:

```
LinkedList<Integer> getPaths(Node parent, int multiple){

    if(parent == null)
        return null;

    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    list = getPaths(parent.getLeftChild(), 5);


    if(parent.getSID() % multiple == 0){
        list.add(parent.getSID());
        return list;
    }

    list = getPaths(parent.getRightChild(),5);

    if(list != null)
        list.add(parent.getSID());

    return list;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I dint find any "?" in your question.

Comment: Yes I have tried and following is the algo I am following:
I traverse in-order and compare the values for multiple of 5. If it is, I start adding the nodes in a LinkedList and return that list back.
But this approach works only if I have one multiple of 5. If there are more multiples, it fails.

Comment: Post such vital information as a part of your question (by editing it).

Comment: Show us your code + potential errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, when you do:

```
list = getPaths(parent.getRightChild(), 5);
```

you overwrite the value returned here:

```
list = getPaths(parent.getLeftChild(), 5);
```

You probably need a `LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>` to store all the paths.

**Either a global list:**

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> globalList;
LinkedList<Integer> getPaths(Node parent, int multiple)
```

**Or passing around the list:**

```
LinkedList<Integer> getPaths(Node parent, int multiple,
                             LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> bigList)
```

Getting this to work will however require quite a bit of changes to your current program, you'll need to copy lists at certain points and probably switch around the order in which you populate the list (change it from populating bottom-up to top-down).